# Default Units of length used in datasheet

Tags: pcb, datasheet

I am trying to make a PCB footprint for the MT2 series relay using datasheet.

Am getting really confused whether the units of dimensions mentioned in the datasheet are mm or inches.

Can't seem to find anywhere what is the unit. Is there a default unit in case of electronic datasheets which should be taken if units are not mentioned?

See this [datasheet.](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Specification%20Or%20Standard%7F108-98006%7FK%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_SS_108-98006_K.pdf%7F1462000-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard but it's not usually difficult to tell.  In this case, the overall dimensions of the relay are given as 10 X 20 mm right near the top left of the first data sheet page.  If you look at the dimensional drawing, the overall dimensions are also given as 10 x 20.  Therefore, it is clear that the units of the dimensional drawings are mm. Since there are 25.4 mm to an inch, it should be obvious in most cases, whether the units are mm or inches.

Answer (score 2):

The units are mm. If they were inches you'd have to drill 0.8" holes for the pins (1). The 2.54 grid equates to 0.1" which is standard grid for DIL integrated circuits, etc. (2).

[image]